# Fibonacci sequence and a problem about halves: why is my code failing hidden tests?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

Currently I am trying two solve two problems. The first one consists of defining a **predicate isFib** which, given a **positive integer**, verifies if that number belongs in the **Fibonacci sequence** (which is 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc. : **F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)**). The second one consists of implementing recursively the function **halves** which receives **two positive integers a and b** and returns a list containing the value *a* (converted to *float*) and **every sucessive halves of a which are larger than b**. The list must be in descending order.

I tried to solve the first problem by creating the following algorithm:

```
def isFib(n):
    num1 = 1
    num2 = 1
    while True:
        if num2 <= n:
            if num2 == n:
                return True
            else:
                tempnum = num2
                num2 += num1
                num1 = tempnum
        else:
            return False
```

And the second one by the following algorithm:

```
def halves(a, b):
    a > 0 and b > 0
    if a//1 != a or b//1 != b or b == 0:
        return None
    halves = []
    while a > b:
        halves.append(a)
        a = a/2
    return [float(x) for x in halves]
```

The output of my code gives me what I want but claims that there my code is *"failing one or more hidden tests"*

*Test:
print(metades(100,3))

Output:
[100.0, 50.0, 25.0, 12.5, 6.25, 3.125]

Test:
print(metades(1,3))

Output:
[]

Test:
print(metades(32,2))

Output:
[32.0, 16.0, 8.0, 4.0]*

Comment: How is the first problem related?

Comment: It's not related, it's just that I am having the same problem in both

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Also, provide a [mcve], along with both the actual and expected output it produces. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @VascoAscensão Can you share the link to the problems?